# Is there a way to register a global helper file for Handlebar.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

I use Handlebar.js to render a template.

```
function renderTemplate(data, templateName) {
  const html = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/templates/template2.hbs`, 'utf8')

  //register one helper
  hbs.registerHelper("formatName", function () {
    return "This is my jam"
  });

  const template = hbs.compile(html)

  const rendered = template(data)
  return rendered
}
```

Now as you can see I can register a helper in the function. However, I might write 10-20 helpers. That way this function gets very 'bloated' en unnecessarily large. Is there a way to register a global `helper.js` file or something a like where I can put all my helpers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. `Handlebars.registerHelper()` allows you to pass in an Object and its keys will be registered as helper functions (see [the Handlebars docs for more info](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/runtime.html#handlebars-registerhelper-name-helper)).

For example, these two are equivalent:

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper({
  foo() {},
  bar() {},
});
```

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper("foo", function(){});
Handlebars.registerHelper("bar", function(){});
```

You could then create a separate JS file that exports this Object. Your `renderTemplate` file then can import this for use.

```js
// hbs-helpers.js
module.exports = {
  foo() {},
  bar() {},
};
```

```js
const hbsHelpers = require('./hbs-helpers.js');

function renderTemplate(data, templateName) {
  const html = fs.readFileSync(`${__dirname}/templates/template2.hbs`, 'utf8');

  // register ALL helpers
  hbs.registerHelper(hbsHelpers);

  const template = hbs.compile(html);
  const rendered = template(data);

  return rendered;
}
```